# Change webpack configuration in angular 7 and change SVG setting for CKEditor 5 to load custom plugin

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm using `ckeditor5-editor-inline` in Angular (not the customized one for angular for some reasons because of the logic we use the editor). When I want to add Plugin I get

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): CKEditorError: Cannot read 
property 'getAttribute' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
at IconView._updateXMLContent (iconview.js:100)
at IconView.render (iconview.js:76)
at IconView.<anonymous> (observablemixin.js:255)
at IconView.fire (emittermixin.js:209)
at IconView.<computed> [as render] (observablemixin.js:259)
at ViewCollection.<anonymous> (viewcollection.js:66)
at ViewCollection.fire (emittermixin.js:209)
at ViewCollection.add (collection.js:182)
at ButtonView.render (buttonview.js:181)
at ButtonView.<anonymous> (observablemixin.js:255)
at ButtonView.fire (emittermixin.js:209)
at ButtonView.<computed> [as render] (observablemixin.js:259)
at Template._renderElementChildren (template.js:710)
at Template._renderElement (template.js:443)
at Template._renderNode (template.js:425)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:831) [angular]
at :4200/polyfills.js:3258:17 [angular]
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290) [angular]
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601) [<root>]
at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:502) [<root>]
at timer (zone.js:2281) [<root>]
```

I realized that it's for loading SVGs and there should be some changes in webpack configuration but how it that possible in angular?

And this is my code for Importing editor:

```
import InlineEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-inline/src/inlineeditor';
import Font from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/font';
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
import Italic from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic';
import Heading from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading';
```

And how I Use it:

```
InlineEditor
        .create(document.getElementById('editable-1'), {
            plugins: [ Essentials, Paragraph, Font, Bold, Italic, Heading, Image ],
          toolbar: [
            'heading', 'fontSize', 'undo', 'redo', 'image'
          ]
          }
        )
        .then(editor => {
          console.log(editor);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
```

any suggestion that can help?

Comment: how did you add 'ckeditor5-editor-inline' to your project. And can you create a minimal stackblitz

Comment: I've updated the question